# imacros help if statements

Tags: firefox, scripting, imacros

In my macro1.iim , I search google for Iron Maiden. If a certain keyword is found in the results (example: the word "eddy") I want to extract the word "eddy" and save it to a text file. If the word is not found I want to wait 10min and search again.

Thinking eval or making a vbs script?
Could someone show me how do I do this?

I've tried this:

```
`VERSION BUILD=7500718 RECORDER=FX
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 15
TAB T=1     
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
URL GOTO=http://google.com/search=ironmaiden/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:eddy EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\";var txt=/eddy/i;
if (s.match(eddy)) iimPlay(macro2)
else WAIT=10000 seconds {{!LOOP}}")`
```

Comment: BTW - that should be *eddie* not *eddy*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it with iMacros JavaScript scripting.

```
//declaring the macro
var macroIronMaiden;

macroIronMaiden ="CODE:";
macroIronMaiden +="VERSION BUILD=7500718 RECORDER=FX"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 15"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="TAB T=1"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT="+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="URL GOTO=http://google.com/search=ironmaiden/"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:eddy EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";



var macroWait;

macroWait ="CODE:";
macroWait +="WAIT SECONDS=600";    
////////Beginning///////


//this loop will search 10 times. Change number 10 for more times

for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{

iimPlay(macroIronMaiden)

var extract=iimGetLastExtract();

if(extract.toLowerCase()=="eddy")
{

//save it to text file
}
else
{

    iimDisplay("Waiting for 10 minutes")
iimPlay(macroWait)
}

}
```

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740337/xpcom-writestring-error/14762088#14762088) to save the data in text file.

Comment: wow thanks man!! And in the iimDisplay("Moving on") part how can i make it wait 10 min and start from the top again (search iron maiden again)???

Comment: Ok I edited the code and now it will do that. :)
For this I only ask upvote. :D

Comment: so once its done waiting 600seconds it starts again from macroIronMaiden? and I will upvote you :D

Comment: ok i tested and it work awesome. I just don't understand how it plays macroIronMaiden again. where does it say start from beginning? thanks IceD

Comment: and i don't have enough rep. to upvote. when i get enough I will :)

Comment: Lol. The loop , restarts the macro each time.

Comment: oh wow. just realized that hahah. and thanks this helped me alot.

Comment: Now you got some reputation. ;) Thanks.

Comment: One last thing man. can you store lots of extracted values? like extract 'eddy', extract 'current url'...etc and save them for later use?

Comment: Yes. Check out the link I wrote in the bottom of my response. Use that function to save the data into a file.